# How to pause a batch operation in photoshop to allow for user interaction?

Tags: post-processing, photoshop

Is there a way to insert a pause into an action to wait for a batch operation? I have a script set up to take the selection from an image and stick it on a white backdrop, and wanted to set it up so that I can stick all the folders that need work into a folder and batch them. In order to do so, I would need it to take a break after opening each new file to allow the user to create a selection. I tried inserting a stop command but if I stop the script, then when I play the rest of the action, the batch operation has ceased.

Comment: Hi there, I'm not seeing the _photography_ aspect of this question. Can you clarify?

Comment: John, I think PS related questions are by nature photo related. Its the equivalent of asking about chemical storage for a darkroom. Maybe not directly relating to f/stops, but still very much about photography.

Comment: @RobClement - That is not the shared feeling of this community. See: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/658/what-should-we-do-with-photoshop-questions, http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1260/where-do-we-draw-the-line-on-photoshop-and-similar-questions, and http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3811/are-photoshop-action-questions-on-topic The community decision has varied over the past on the exact way to handle these, but I think the main differentiation is does this apply to a photo? And in this case I'm not sure.

Comment: @RobClement Photoshop is a powerful program, also used for artistic image creation and manipulation, and for graphic design. Superuser.com is better for general software questions; here, they should be in the context of photographic problems and solutions.

Comment: "Chemical storage for a darkroom" is a great example. Those last three words make all the difference.

Comment: Sorry if this was off topic here, but which forum would this best be asked on? I submitted two questions regarding Photoshop the other day on here and I apologize if this is not the right place, but it would seem to me that Photoshop typically deals with photography. Can you suggest a better place to post these types of questions, and would someone be able to migrate both of my questions to that site, or would it be better if I just started a new post on that site?

Comment: As it's photoshop automation it's off topic for photo.se, it might be a better fit for graphicdesign.se as they have a photoshop scripting tag?

Comment: It can be done with extendscript programming where step 1 gets the list and opens the first image then then you bind a key or a button to tell the script when the selection is complete (it then closes/saves and opens the next one).  To do it in a way as simply using 'stop' is not trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You can only stop exection. See [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-7448a.html) link.

> Insert a stop
>
> You can include stops in an action that let you perform a task that
>   cannot be recorded (for example, using a painting tool). After you
>   complete the task, click the Play button in the Actions panel to
>   complete the action.
>
> You can also display a short message when the action reaches the stop
>   as a reminder of what needs to be done before continuing with the
>   action. You can include a Continue button in the message box in case
>   no other task needs to be done.
>
> 1. Choose where to insert the stop by doing one of the following:
>
>    - Select an action’s name to insert a stop at the end of the action.
>    - Select a command to insert a stop after the command.
> 2. Choose Insert Stop from the Actions panel menu.
> 3. Type the message you want to appear.
> 4. If you want the option to continue the action without stopping, select Allow Continue.
> 5. Click OK.

Answer (score 0):

As of PS CS3 (I know, I know) the "Stop" command is the best thing you've got. I have several actions that would be awesome if I could build in one pause that, once my intervention was executed, would finish the action and activate the next file. I've looked high and low and can not find anything like this.

My advice is re-think your workflow. Maybe batch the first portion of your script for all images, then create a second action for the second half of the operation.

Another idea: since you're talking about folder structures, take a look at a browser automation like Apple's "Automater."

Good luck.